# Selector can't find instance method

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to register a method as an action for a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` within my view controller. The target view is a custom view that I've built with a `UIView` subclass, as that's where I want the swipe targeted at. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to set the action to be a method in the `UIViewController`. I can do that when I drag/drop the gesture to the View in interface builder, and then drag out an action to the controller.

```
func swiped(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
}

func addGestureToView(_ view: CardView) {
    let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: Selector("swiped:"))
    gesture.direction = .up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}
```

I've also tried to use

`let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(swiped(_:)))`

Both of these approaches gives me the following exception of:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[testapp.CardView swiped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I assume that is because it is looking for `swiped:` within the `CardView` target, and not the method that exists in the Controller. How can I specify that I want it to use the Controller for the action, while applying the gesture itself *only* to the `CardView`?

Comment: hey @Johnathon Sullinger please see my answer again I have updated my answer, use need to use  **self** instead of **view**

Comment: change let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(swiped(_:)))
to 
let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped(_:)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line :

```
let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: Selector("swiped:"))
```

to:

```
let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped(_:)))
```

**Explanation**

**target:** in UISwipeGestureRecognizer defines where your action method will be called, by defining self we are telling that our swipe gesture action should be called from UIViewcontroller not from CardView

**action:** in UISwipeGestureRecognizer defines the method that should be called on swipe gesture.

Comment: please write **#selector(** and then using auto complete type swiped method name it will write something like **#selector(swiped(:_))** or  **#selector(swiped:)**which is correct way

Comment: Changing the target to `self` worked. I didn't realize that was the target for the selector and not the target for the gesture itself (which is set using `addGestureRecognizer:`. Thanks

Comment: welcome sorry for my mistake it was due to giving answer without running it on actual complier